# Школьный сис.админ

Tags: администрирование

Приглашают быть техническим инженером или сис.админом в школе и в колледже искусств.
В школе платят больше, поэтому думаю туда. 
Может кто имеет опыт работы в школе, подскажите какие знания и умения нужны.
Какие технологии, какие типы локальных сетей обычно используются в школах?
Где почитать как ими управлять?
Сразу говорю, ОС - windows Xp, компы хрень, непонятно зачем купили свежего каспера на 3 года вперёд.

Comment: имхо лучше приобщится к исскуству чем к группе агрошкольников. хотя часто такие проблемы с "виндой" решаются так: пароль на биос + автоматическая загрузкой по сети + форматирование дисков (диска С) + репликация образа на компьютер.

Answer (score 4):

Если это обычная школа, то надо уметь решать проблемы:

1. "Ой, там компьютер что-то не включается"...
2. "Ой, у меня не получается сделать то-то"...
3. "Ой, а принтер не хочет печатать"...
4. "Ой, а там интернета нет"...

Ну и всё в таком духе. Проблемы с ОС, с программами, с компьютерами как таковыми, с периферией, настройка новых рабочих мест.

Answer (score 2):

Закаляйте летом нервы — они вам пригодятся, когда будете устранять последствия проделок «продвинутых» учеников.

Comment: Для того, чтобы не пришлось тратить впустую лето, достаточно продумать систему разделения прав и архитектуру сети. Понятное дело, что ставить ХР со стандартными настройками - череповато, т.к. детки сразу получат права администратора и будут куролесить по полной. В школе, которую я закончил, у нас было вообще хитро - ДОС, грузящийся по сетке, у каждого пользователя свой подмонтированный сетевой диск и общий в режиме "только чтение" с программами. Для винды такое сделать сложновато, но можно как минимум дать деткам права максимум пользователя. И сделать образы винчестеров для быстрого рекавери.

Comment: А еще можно поставить Линукс и пользоваться вовсю технологиями виртуализации.

Comment: А нам блокировали винду какой-то нездоровой прогой, название не вспомню, но да, "только чтение". Тем не менее почему-то паскаль довольно спокойно создавал батник и пихал его в автозагрузку... Прогу сняли на следующий день, т.к. запускался только учительский комп. В общем, совет дельный и дополню - от дурака защиты нет) Только от ленивого)

Comment: Согласен с gecube (у нас в свое время было тоже нечто подобное).
Ещё среди перечисленных навыков.. Ну.. Не знаю как у вас, но насколько мне известно, ещё не плохо бы на определенном уровне владеть офисными приложениями, т.к. у преподавателей (как и учеников) бывают проблемы.
+ если там есть олимпиады по информатике\веб-дизайну, то было бы не плохо уметь ставить apache + php + mysql. Мелочи, но всё же...
Ну а так в целом всё остальное уже кое как можно подогнать под вышесказанные критерии.

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть в школе опыт, огромное количество нерв испортишь и + ко всему этому быдешь сталкиваться с настолько глупыми пролемами с которыми справился бы любой дошкольник:
У меня были такие случаи:
 - колонки не работают
 - Драйвер слетел
 - пуск стал большим
 - Панельки в офисе исчезли